# Button on pop Up View doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to create a button on my custom pop up view. But created button doesn't recognise its action.

```
func createPopUp(){
    view.userInteractionEnabled = false
    scrollerView.userInteractionEnabled = false
    var screenSize:CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    var screenHeight = screenSize.height
    var screenWidth = screenSize.width

    var popUpView : UIImageView
    popUpView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 530, 150));
    popUpView.center = CGPointMake(screenWidth/2,screenHeight/2)
    popUpView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    popUpView.tag = 81
    self.view.addSubview(popUpView)

    var vazgecButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    vazgecButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 265, 60)
    vazgecButton.center = CGPointMake(250, 550)
    vazgecButton.setTitle("Vazgeç", forState: .Normal)
    vazgecButton.tag = 79
    vazgecButton.addTarget(self, action: "closePopUpView:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(vazgecButton)
}
```

First i disabled user interacton for view and my scrollerView. Then i created a image view for pop up view, to keep my button. Neither adding on to popUpView nor view work.

and my closePopUpView is:

```
func closePopUpView(sender: UIButton!){
    println("pressed!!")
}
```

I searched for internet but i couldn't find a solution.